# htaccess rewrite from subdomain (root) to www (root) without 301 redirect

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am having error in rewriting url. I want the request 
http://go.example.com/all-pathnames-flenames

should be handled by some page 
http://www.example.com/myfile.php

It should not be hard or 301 redirect (rather original url should be there).

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^go\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /myfile.php [L]
```

above mentioned is the code i have but it is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to exclude rewriting `myfile.php`, otherwise you'll create a loop:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^go\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/myfile.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /myfile.php [L]
```

Comment: thanks, only one more twist. it gives error if the location of subdomains (www and go ) is not same on server. please suggest some work around.

Comment: your solution was perfect for me, in the first attempt. though i took time to figure out things i was doing. thanks jon.